# Mongo & Angular 2

Tags: mongodb, angular

I would like to know how to integrate a Mongo database (to store information, a form ...) in an angular 2 project
If you have a tutorial, documents that give me a step to follow, do not hesitate, I wait for your answers to unlock me

Comment: seriously, what's holding you back from entering "mongodb angular2" into your favorite search engine?

Answer (score 0):

The process is actually fairly simple. Here is the run down of the basics you will need...

1. Create your api to handle your CRUD operations
2. Create your Database in MongoDB
3. Create your angular 2 service to handle CRUD functions to API
4. Create an angular 2 service to call out to your running API

I have a Github of how I did it as well as the sources of the tutorials that I followed: https://github.com/bcrawford11/Angular2-w-CRUD-Api-MongoDb